# Redundant words -- "little bit"

Tags: redundancy

> He sandwiches tastier by spreading a **little bit** of cranberry sauce on the bread.

In the above sentence, is "little bit" redundant? Should it be either "little" or "bit"?

I checked the pair of words in books.google.com/ngrams, and the result was;
[image: google-ngram]

[language-tool](https://languagetool.org/) says, "Reduce redundancy by using 'little' or 'bit'.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Little" or "bit" could stand on its own, but "[little bit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20little%20bit)" is OK because it's idiomatic. It's not redundant the way "ATM machine" (automated teller machine machine) is.